# How to match a specific number range with a regex

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

For example I have a data which contains the process name and time take by it.

```
process1   Age 3 min
process2   Age 32 min
process3   Age 1243 min
....
....
processN   Age 12031 min
```

And what I want is to get the results above 60.

Comment: Does it have to use a regex?

Comment: Process number above 60 or age above 60? [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output plus what you've tried so far. Use the editors `{}` button to format the input/output/code. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use awk, this will output all entries with an age over 60:

```
awk '$3 > 60' datafile
```

Comment: Or to put it more concisely, `awk '$3 > 60'  datafile`.

Comment: @Samadi Thanks :)